# Get mouse position in a QImage

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qimage

I need to get the coordinates of a QImage of where the mouse is currently hovering. Like in image editing programs, where we can see the coordinates of the pixel the mouse in currently hovering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `setMouseTracking(true)`, and override `mouseMoveEvent`. Your `mouseMoveEvent` function will be called whenever the mouse moves inside the QImage. (You have to create a subclass of QImage to do this.)

Comment: To be able to capture an event you subclassing is not the only solution... You can too use the eventFilter function: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/eventsandfilters.html